# Changing the color of specific area of shapefile using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, plot

I have this map and I need to emphasize with a different color some cities from this map:

[image: map]

This is my code:

```
import json
import time
import geopandas as gpd
import adjustText as aT
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import LineString

borough = gpd.read_file('London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp')
borough = borough.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})



borough["center"] = borough["geometry"].centroid
borough_points = borough.copy()
borough_points.set_geometry("center", inplace = True)


texts = []

ax = borough.plot(column=None, cmap='ocean', edgecolor = "black", linewidth = 1, alpha=0.5, 
                  categorical=False, legend=False, axes=None, figsize=(40,20))

for x, y, label in zip(borough_points.geometry.x, borough_points.geometry.y, borough_points["NAME"]):
    texts.append(plt.text(x, y, label, fontsize = 12))

aT.adjust_text(texts, force_points=0.3, force_text=0.8, expand_points=(1,1), expand_text=(1,1), 
               arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color='grey', lw=0.5))

x, y = df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values
ax.scatter(x,y, marker="*", color='r', zorder=5, alpha=0.7, s=18)
ax.set_ylim([51.65, 51.40])
ax.set_xlim([-0.4, 0.2])

plt.show
```

Could someone show me the right direction to do it?

Comment: Could you please describe how you would like the cities styled?